# Posición de los input y alineamiento del width entre ellos

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy realizando un "proyecto" para clase y al aplicar unos estilos al formulario los `input` de este tienen un 100% del `width` con respecto al `div` que lo contiene, estoy intentando que los `input` estén ocupen el mismo ancho que los botones de Entrar, Registrarse y Olvide mi Contraseña?. A continuación dejo los css y el html.

```css
/*CSS del formulario, este css contiene los estilos del formulario  */

/* FORMULARIOS */

.cont-formulario{
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}

.sesion{
    padding-top: 20px;
}

input[type=text] {
    outline: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ff851b;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

input[type=password] {
    outline: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ff851b;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

input[type=email] {
    outline: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ff851b;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

input[type=number] {
    outline: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ff851b;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
  
input[type=submit] {
    background: #ff851b;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #0075d9;
}

input[type=password]:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #0075d9;
}

input[type=email]:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #0075d9;
}

input[type=number]:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #0075d9;
}
  
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 117, 217, 0.7);
}

.negativo{
    border-color: red !important;
}
.positivo{
    border-color: green !important;
}

.toggle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 2px solid #ff851b;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff851b;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle span{
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.toggle:hover{
    border-top: 2px solid #0075d9;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0075d9;
}

.box5 h2{
    margin: 0 0 28px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
}

.reset-password{
    background: rgba(0, 117, 217, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.reset-password a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.box5 .formulario{
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: none;
}

.box5 .formulario:nth-child(2){
    display: block;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #fff; } 
 
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */ color: #fff; } 
 
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */ color: #fff; } 
 
:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #fff; }

:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:transparent;}



/*---------- CSS GENERAL -----------*/
/*CSS general, aquí tengo el grid y otros que son comunes para todos los html*/


*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* CSS GRID */
.container{
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 3fr 0.25fr;
}

.box{
    background: slateblue;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.box4{
    background: midnightblue;
}

.box5{
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3{
    background: #000;
}

.box7, .box8, .box9{
    background: maroon;
}

/* MENU HEADER */
header{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #000;
}

ul, ol{
    list-style: none;
}

.ul_nav li a{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
}

.ul_nav li a:hover{
    background-color: #434343;
}

.ul_nav > li{
    float: left;
}

/* MENU LATERAL IZQUIERDO */

.menuIzquierdo{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: left;
}

.menuIzquierdo > li > a{
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: midnightblue;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

.menuIzquierdo > li > a:hover{
    background: cornflowerblue;
}

/* FECHA */
.fecha{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 125px;
    border-style: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.ano, .mes{
    font-size: .75em;
}

.ano{
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

.dia{
    background-color: darkseagreen;
}

.mes{
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

/* PIE DE PAGINA */

.liPiePag{
    text-align: left;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.liPiePag li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.liPiePag li a:hover{
    color: #ff851b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <title>Eventos Deportivos</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script src="../js/login.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/calendario.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/avLegal.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/reg.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/us.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/formulario.css"/>
 </head>
 <body onload="calendario()">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="box box1"></div>
   <div class="box box2">
    <header>
     <nav>
      <ul class="ul_nav">
       <li><a href="../index.html">HOME</a></li>
       <li><a href="./utilidades.html">Utilidades</a></li>
       <li><a href="./otro.html">Otro</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Login/Reg</a></li>
       <li><a href="./mas.html">Más</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </header>
   </div>
   <div class="box box3">
    <div class="fecha ano" id="year"></div>
    <div class="fecha dia" id="day"></div>
    <div class="fecha mes" id="month"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="box box4" id="menIzq"></div>
   <div class="box box5" id="contenido">
    <div class="cont-formulario">
     <div class="toggle">
      <span> Crear Cuenta</span>
     </div>
     <div class="formulario">
      <h2 class="sesion">Iniciar Sesion</h2>
      <form id="log" class="" method="GET" onsubmit="return compr()">
       <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre..."/>
       <label for="nombre" id="labNombre"></label>
       <input type="password" id="pass" class="" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña..."/>
       <label for="pass" id="labPass"></label>
       <input onclick="compr();" type="submit" value="Entrar"/>
      </form>
     </div>
     <div class="formulario">
      <h2 class="sesion">Crea tu Cuenta</h2>
      <form method="GET" onsubmit="return valRegistro()">
       <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="Nombre..." required/>
       <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido..." required/>
       <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..." required/>
       <input type="password" id="passw" name="passw" placeholder="Contraseña..." required/>
       <input type="password" id="reppassw" name="reppassw" placeholder="Repetir contraseña..." required/>
       <input type="submit" onclick="valRegistro();" value="Registrarse"/>
      </form>
     </div>
     <div class="reset-password">
      <a href="#" onclick="users();">Olvide mi Contraseña?</a>
     </div>
    </div>
            </div>
   <div class="box">Menu lateral derecho</div>
   <div class="box box7"></div>
   <div class="box box8">
    <ul class="liPiePag">
     <li>Asociación/Clube/Empresa</li>
     <li>Web desarrollada por: Julio Pillado Castillo</li>
     <li><a href="" onclick="avisoLegal();">Aviso legal</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="box box9"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="../js/jqueryv-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema está en este selector de `css`:

```
input[type=text] {
    ...
    padding: 10px 15px;
    ...
}

input[type=password]{
    ...
    padding: 10px 15px;
    ...
}
```

Para solucionarlo quítale el `padding` de los laterales al `input`:

```
input[type=text] {
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
/*CSS del formulario, este css contiene los estilos del formulario  */

/* FORMULARIOS */

.cont-formulario{
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}

.sesion{
    padding-top: 20px;
}

input[type=text] {
    outline: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ff851b;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

input[type=password] {
    outline: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ff851b;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

input[type=email] {
    outline: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ff851b;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

input[type=number] {
    outline: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ff851b;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
  
input[type=submit] {
    background: #ff851b;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #0075d9;
}

input[type=password]:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #0075d9;
}

input[type=email]:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #0075d9;
}

input[type=number]:focus {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #0075d9;
}
  
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 117, 217, 0.7);
}

.negativo{
    border-color: red !important;
}
.positivo{
    border-color: green !important;
}

.toggle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 2px solid #ff851b;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff851b;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle span{
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.toggle:hover{
    border-top: 2px solid #0075d9;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0075d9;
}

.box5 h2{
    margin: 0 0 28px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
}

.reset-password{
    background: rgba(0, 117, 217, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.reset-password a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.box5 .formulario{
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: none;
}

.box5 .formulario:nth-child(2){
    display: block;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #fff; } 
 
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */ color: #fff; } 
 
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */ color: #fff; } 
 
:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #fff; }

:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:transparent;}



/*---------- CSS GENERAL -----------*/
/*CSS general, aquí tengo el grid y otros que son comunes para todos los html*/


*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* CSS GRID */
.container{
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 3fr 0.25fr;
}

.box{
    background: slateblue;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.box4{
    background: midnightblue;
}

.box5{
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3{
    background: #000;
}

.box7, .box8, .box9{
    background: maroon;
}

/* MENU HEADER */
header{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #000;
}

ul, ol{
    list-style: none;
}

.ul_nav li a{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
}

.ul_nav li a:hover{
    background-color: #434343;
}

.ul_nav > li{
    float: left;
}

/* MENU LATERAL IZQUIERDO */

.menuIzquierdo{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: left;
}

.menuIzquierdo > li > a{
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: midnightblue;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

.menuIzquierdo > li > a:hover{
    background: cornflowerblue;
}

/* FECHA */
.fecha{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 125px;
    border-style: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.ano, .mes{
    font-size: .75em;
}

.ano{
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

.dia{
    background-color: darkseagreen;
}

.mes{
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

/* PIE DE PAGINA */

.liPiePag{
    text-align: left;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.liPiePag li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.liPiePag li a:hover{
    color: #ff851b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <title>Eventos Deportivos</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script src="../js/login.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/calendario.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/avLegal.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/reg.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/us.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/formulario.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="box box1"></div>
   <div class="box box2">
    <header>
     <nav>
      <ul class="ul_nav">
       <li><a href="../index.html">HOME</a></li>
       <li><a href="./utilidades.html">Utilidades</a></li>
       <li><a href="./otro.html">Otro</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Login/Reg</a></li>
       <li><a href="./mas.html">Más</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </header>
   </div>
   <div class="box box3">
    <div class="fecha ano" id="year"></div>
    <div class="fecha dia" id="day"></div>
    <div class="fecha mes" id="month"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="box box4" id="menIzq"></div>
   <div class="box box5" id="contenido">
    <div class="cont-formulario">
     <div class="toggle">
      <span> Crear Cuenta</span>
     </div>
     <div class="formulario">
      <h2 class="sesion">Iniciar Sesion</h2>
      <form id="log" class="" method="GET" onsubmit="return compr()">
       <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre..."/>
       <label for="nombre" id="labNombre"></label>
       <input type="password" id="pass" class="" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña..."/>
       <label for="pass" id="labPass"></label>
       <input onclick="compr();" type="submit" value="Entrar"/>
      </form>
     </div>
     <div class="formulario">
      <h2 class="sesion">Crea tu Cuenta</h2>
      <form method="GET" onsubmit="return valRegistro()">
       <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="Nombre..." required/>
       <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido..." required/>
       <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..." required/>
       <input type="password" id="passw" name="passw" placeholder="Contraseña..." required/>
       <input type="password" id="reppassw" name="reppassw" placeholder="Repetir contraseña..." required/>
       <input type="submit" onclick="valRegistro();" value="Registrarse"/>
      </form>
     </div>
     <div class="reset-password">
      <a href="#" onclick="users();">Olvide mi Contraseña?</a>
     </div>
    </div>
            </div>
   <div class="box">Menu lateral derecho</div>
   <div class="box box7"></div>
   <div class="box box8">
    <ul class="liPiePag">
     <li>Asociación/Clube/Empresa</li>
     <li>Web desarrollada por: Julio Pillado Castillo</li>
     <li><a href="" onclick="avisoLegal();">Aviso legal</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="box box9"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="../js/jqueryv-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @x3k_js. Ya probé a cambiar el `padding` de los laterales tal y como sugeriste y se soluciono el problema

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta que te da el compañero en es perfectamente válida en su primera opción, necesitas darle las mismas características a través del css para que puedan comportarse del mismo modo a los `input text` e `input password` que al `input submit`. Pero supongo que al probar esta opción te has dado cuanta de que el `placeholder` se te coloca pegado a la izquierda y no quieres este efecto es por este motivo que que debes añair en tu css lo siguiente:

```
input[type=text] {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

input[type=password]{
    padding: 10px 0;
}

input[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    padding-left:15px;
}
input[type=text]:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   padding-left:15px;
   opacity:  1;
}
input[type=text]::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   padding-left:15px;
   opacity:  1;
}
input[type=text]:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
   padding-left:15px
} 

input[type=password]::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    padding-left:15px;
}
input[type=password]:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   padding-left:15px;
   opacity:  1;
}
input[type=password]::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   padding-left:15px;
   opacity:  1;
}
input[type=password]:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
   padding-left:15px
}
```

Comment: Al hacer el cambio sugerido por @x3k_js tuve darle el `padding-left:15px;` para que no quedase el `placeholder` pegado a la izquierda. Gracias @JorgeGuz